# Can a Vienna rectifier or an active front end rectifier regulate the voltage down?

Tags: ac, dc, rectifier

I learn the basics of rectifiers. In particular, Vienna rectifier and active front end recifier.

As I understand it, both types of rectifiers can work in the mode of increasing the output voltage.

But so far it’s not very clear to me whether they can work in the mode of lowering the output voltage.

1. Vienna rectifier

[image]

I see here six diodes that rectify alternating current and are not regulated by anything. But also with them on each phase there are two MOSFET transistors, which, as I understand it, act as additional "regulated" diodes.

Does this rectifier circuit provide the possibility of lowering the voltage below the level obtained from 6 diodes?

2. Active front end rectifier

[image]

In this circuit, there is already complete control of each of the transistors.

**Main questions:**

1. Can these types of rectifiers reduce the output voltage?
2. Can an active front end rectifier increase the output voltage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Vienna rectifier is pretty much exclusively used for making power-factor corrected (PFC) three-phase DC supplies. The working principle (as with any single-phase PFC) is that boost control is used to produce a DC voltage that is (usually) significantly higher than the peak AC voltage. Only in this way can proper PFC be achieved.

> *This rectifier circuit does not provide the possibility of lowering
> the voltage below the level obtained from 6 diodes?*

No it doesn't because to adequately perform power factor correction, the rectified bus DC voltage has the be higher than the peak AC voltage. Then a step-down DC-to-DC converter takes the bus voltage to a lower usable level.

---

The active front-end rectifier in your 2nd circuit is also a boost circuit and can deliver a power factor corrected DC bus voltage but, again, it will be higher than the peak AC voltage.

Comment: thank you for the answer!