# How does an AFE boost voltage?

Tags: converter, ac-dc

I have an active front end unit that is connected to a 3 phase system. It's controlled via software and I can set a value for the DC bus voltage.

When the input is the AC 3-phase, how does this circuit charge the DC cap to a voltage beyond the rectified voltage of the 3 phase?  I can take a 240AC 3-phase input and set it to output a 500 volts bus.

I have some understanding about how it works when going from DC to AC: using dqZ transforms and space vector modulation. But I'm confused as to how it is able to boost voltage from the 3 phase to the DC bus.

[image]

Comment: With inductor on the input, you have yourself a boost converter if you switch accordingly. Have you tried to simulate it?

Comment: I see. So it's like 3 boost converters in parallel? I'm not familiar with how a boost converter would work when the input is AC though. I don't have a way to simulate the control loop unfortunately. Is there a name for this?

Comment: Pretty much yes. The control loop becomes a bit more complicated with AC input, but just take a snapshot of just one phase and one leg and see the input as DC. Now you have a synchronous boost converter.

Comment: [Similar but by no means a duplicate question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/510533/can-a-vienna-rectifier-or-an-active-front-end-rectifier-regulate-the-voltage-dow) <-- might help if using vienna rectifier term to search for how it boosts.

Comment: Apart from the obvious fact that the rectifier is an active rectifier (as Andya mentioned, Vienna Rectifier)... `I can take a 240AC 3-phase input and set it to output a 500 volts bus.` If a 3P with 240 Vrms phase voltage (not line voltage) is rectified with an ordinary full bridge rectifier the voltage across the capacitor would be ~580 VDC (simply, RMS phase voltage in Volts times square root of six) which is much higher than 500V. In other words, 500 VDC is not beyond the 3P rectified voltage.

Comment: I believe this is a 2 level AFE which is a different topology than the Vienna rectifier. Where does square root of 6 come from? I thought the RMS of a rectified 3 phase wave is 1.65xRMS of the phase V.